# How To Load an HTML File As A WordPress Page (With No 301/No Redirect)

Tags: customization, permalinks, templates, redirect, page-template

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Page URL: `https://example.com/the-page/`

What it should load: `https://example.com/content/oct2020/index.html`

When visitors go to the permalink /the-page/, I'd like that permalink to stay exactly the same. But instead of loading content & template files from the WordPress database, it would just display the index.html file instead.

I do *not* want someone to visit "/the-page/" permalink, and then be 301'd to https://example.com/content/oct2020/index.html.

I know this can be done with a Page Template, but then I'd need all the files to be inside my WP themes directory. Instead I want to host these HTML files in a separate directory, totally theme-agnostic. Is there a plugin offering this kind of functionality, or would it be easy to code up as a functions.php addon? Or would the easiest solution be adding a line into my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`template_include` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) to accomplish this.

Add this to your active theme's `functions.php` file (or [create a plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)).

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse376643_load_html_page' );
function wpse376643_load_html_page( $template ) {
    if ( is_page( 'the-page' ) ) {
        // You'll have to use the server path to your index.html file.
        $template = '/path/to/your/content/oct2020/index.html';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution given so far, because it actually addresses my question (ie. the files on my server **will not** match the URL). I need a way to make the URL be any customized string of characters that I want, even if my server's folder structure does not correlate. Thanks for the response I will try this if it's generally the simplest option

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a new empty folder in the root folder of your WordPress website. Typically, it is located here: /public_html/. So, the location of our HTML template will be /public_html/landing/, where ‘landing’ is the name of the folder with our template. The page will be available at http://www.domain.com/landing/. There are many ways to upload files to your hosting. You can use a standalone file manager (e.g. Total Commander or FileZilla).

Comment: The 'better way' here is the correct answer.  I'd edit out the Elementor reference because OP wants the HTML to be theme agnostic/independent.

Comment: Thank you will edit it

Comment: This answer is the correct way. It'll be quicker to load than my `template_include` solution, because the file at `{site root}/the-page/index.html` won't have to load WordPress prior to displaying anything.

Comment: @PatJ @Tony This is not a solution to my specific question. In my example the files are located at `/content/oct2020/`, however that cannot be the URL. So I need a way to customize the URL to be anything(ex: "/my-page-here/") but the files cannot be located in a folder on the server literally titled "my-page-here".